URDF Model Appears Flipped in Foxglove Studio with ROS 2
I'm experiencing an issue with my robot visualization:

The robot model displays correctly in RViz2
However, when viewing in Foxglove Studio, the same model appears flipped
The URDF and robot_description topic are working properly

Has anyone encountered this behaviour? What might be causing this difference between RViz2 and Foxglove?

Environment:

ROS 2 Foxy
Foxglove Studio
RViz2


SOLVED!

If you're using .dae  files like me, there's an <up_axis> tag that defines the "up" direction for the model (like Z-up or Y-up).

In RViz2, this tag is ignored, so your models usually look fine.
However, Foxglove actually uses the <up_axis>, and if it's set differently, the model might appear flipped or weird.

Solution:

Go to the 3D panel settings in Foxglove.
Find Scene -> Mesh "up" axis.
Try toggling between Y-up and Z-up to match RViz2's behavior
Refresh the view, and your model should display correctly.

Hope that helps! :)

For more details, check out the following resources:

GitHub Discussion on Up Axis Issue
Foxglove 3D Panel Documentation
Foxglove Bug Report on Up Axis Handling

